# Access database using petapoco and XML EXPLICIT

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, data-access-layer, petapoco

I have this SQL Server query that uses XML Explicit

```
SELECT 1 AS Tag, NULL AS Parent, NULL AS 'Agents!1!'
FOR XML EXPLICIT
```

I need use petapoco to obtains this results... can I make this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You should use `XML EXPLICIT` when you need that the DB outputs XML, generally from web services.

Petapoco isn't made for that.

You can get the data in a list and then generate the XML and return the value.

Comment: I need FOR XML because I don't know xml structure (user can change structure) and I need return and XML